# parking 5 cars in a 18 parking spaces

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am having an argument with a colleague:
What is the probability of parking 5 cars in a 18 - space parking so that they are always together?

I have the following  5 cars can be arranged 5 ways among themselves. 
Then looking at them as one item then I can arrange all in 14 spaces so 14P5.

Hence Probability is (5*14P5)/ 18P5 , am I right?

Comment: Does it matter, where each car parks ? Or is only important, where the $5$ cars park , no matter in which order ?

Comment: If the spaces are in a line and not in a circle, which I assume, then, there are $14$ arrangements such that all the cars are neighboured, namely $1-2-3-4-5$ , $2-3-4-5-6$ , $\cdots$ , $14-15-16-17-18$. $\binom{18}{5}$ arrangements are possible, so the answer should be $$\frac{14}{\binom{18}{5}}$$ if I do not miss something

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order in which cars are parked does not matter (they just have to be together), the answer is as follows:$$\frac{14\times 5!}{^{18}P_5}$$
14 is the number of possible positions of the 5 cars (order is arbitrary), $5!$ is the number of possible orders of the cars, and $^{18}P_5$ is the total number of possibilites for the cars parked.

This simplifies to:$$\frac{1680}{1028160}$$Which is: $\frac{1}{719}\approx 0.0013908205841446453$

To be exact: $0.0$, followed by a recurring $358$ characters shown below:

0139082058414464534075104311543810848400556328233657858136300417246175243393602225312934631432545201668984700973574408901251738525730180806675938803894297635605006954102920723226703755215577190542420027816411682892906815020862308762169680111265646731571627260083449235048678720445062586926286509040333796940194714881780250347705146036161335187760778859527121

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is $^{18}P_5$ -- this should be clear. Suppose the cars are all next to each other now, so it's one big car that takes up 5 spaces. There are 14 places to put this big car. Finally, this big car can be made up of $5!$ different permutations, so your answer is

$$
\frac{14 \cdot 5!}{^{18}P_5} = \frac{14 \cdot 5!}{18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16\cdot 15\cdot 14} \approx 0.00163398692
$$

Comment: An equivalent answer ignoring order would give $\dfrac{14}{^{18}C_5}$

Comment: agreed and satisfied. The 5 need be 5! Thank you.